# How to read the returned value in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a list and and i need the listvalues to get in another page
I don't know how to read the list values.

**EXAMPLE** in frame1 I have a list I returned the list to frame2 but
I don't know how to read the list in frame2.

My code is:

```
private void EmployeeListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
 List<EmployeeItem> trainitem = new List<EmployeeItem>();
 EmployeeItem item = EmployeeListView.SelectedItem as EmployeeItem;
    
 if(item != null)
 {
  trainitem.Add(item);
 }
             
 Frame.Navigate(typeof(SelectTrainingPlan),trainitem);
}
```

I need to read the trainitem in the frame2 `SelectTrainingPlan`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the SelectTrainingPlan page you can override a method [OnNavigatedTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto?view=winrt-22621) and get your list like

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) 
{
    var yourList = e.Parameter as List<EmployeeItem>;
}
```